# Solutions for $\sum_nA_n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}=B$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I was solving a problem and I encountered the following partial differential equation:

$$\sum_nA_n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}=B$$
where $A_n$ and B are constants and $f:\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the function we are trying to find. I have some knowledge on Ordinary differential equations, so I have no idea how to solve this or if it's even possible to solve it. Does such function $f$  exists? If so how do I solve the equasion?

Comment: The left hand side is a directional derivative. You may want to check the method of characteristics. In your particular case, $f$ is any function that grows linearly in the direction of the vector of $(A_1,A_2,\dots)$. You need some initial data, the value of $f$ on some hyper surface.

Comment: one of my initial conditions is that $f(0,...,0)=0$, so that would mean that B=0, simplifying the equation to: $\sum_nA_n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}=0$

Comment: To get a unique solution, you need to specify $f$ not just at a point but on a whole hypersurface, for example on some $x_i=0$ (a coordinate hyperplane).

Comment: @GReyes But without specifying is it possible to get a general solution?

Comment: $f(0)=0$ does not mean that $B=0$. for example, in 1 dimension, i.e. $n=1$, your differential equation simplifies to $Af'(x)=B$, i.e. $f'(x)=B/A$, so $f(x)=Bx/A+C$ for some constant $C$.

Comment: You're right @Botond

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a particular case of the method of characteristics, which works for very general equations of order one, even non-linear. We can assume that $A=(A_1,A_2,\dots A_n)\neq 0$, Otherwise any differentiable function would be a solution if $B=0$ or there is no solution if $B\neq 0$. Suppose $A_1\neq 0$. The left hand side of your equation is just the derivative of $f$ along a straight line with direction vector $A$ through the given point. This is just the chain rule,
$$
\frac{df(x(t))}{dt}=\nabla f\cdot \frac{dx}{dt}=\nabla f\cdot A.
$$
Therefore, given a point $x$, you consider a line through it with direction vector $A$ and you move along it until you hit a point where $f$ is known and integrate the resulting ODE from there. Under the assumption $A_1\neq 0$, if you know the value of $f$ on the coordinate plane $x_1=0$, the intersection of that line with the coordinate plane is
$(0,y_2,y_3,\dots y_n)$ such that 
$$
x-(0,y_2,y_3\dots y_n)=At
$$
for some $t$, which gives you $t=x_1/A_1$ and $y_i=A_it=A_ix_1/A_1$. According to your equation, $f$ increases linearly in $t$, with rate $B$. That is,
$$
f(x)=f(0,y_2,y_3\dots y_n)+Bt=f(0,A_2x_1/A_1,A_3x_1/A_1,\dots A_nx_1/A_1)+
$$
$$
+bx_1/A_1
$$
which is an explicit formula for the solution.

If you only know $f(0)=0$ you have infinitely many degrees of freedom for your solution. You have as many as (differentiable) functions $g$ of $n-1$ variables satisfying $g(0)=0$.

The same argument applies in general, choosing a hyperplane transversal to the vector $A$ (such hyperplanes are called non-characteristic in the general theory, and are the ones where the boundary values determine a unique solution).